# Changing the representaion of numbers in lisp?

Tags: lisp

I a relatively newcomer to lisp and trying to understand how the behaviour of (common) lisp code can be changed programatically.

I have in mind a simple (but entirely academic) example that I'm trying to resolve where certain numeric digits in the source text are replaced. I'm aware of using macros which can manipulate s-expressions, but would like something which applies globally. So anywhere the number 4 appears (for example), the value 5 is used. So, (+ 4 1) would evaluated to 6 and 44 would evaluate to 55.

To clarify, this is the extremely dumb, simplistic approach where any character 4 is treated as if the programmer had actually typed a 5.

In principle this could be extended to every digit (0 to 9), and assigning them another "meaning", but I'm not so much interested in implementation as I am in an example of some kind of transformation of this sort.

Comment: For the lexical syntax, you might be able to define all 10 digits as reader macros or something.

Comment: This can be answered. This is totally foobar, but I believe you can solve this in several ways and you can make it happen for all read numbers regardless of the size. BUT it will of course only happen ti literals. When you do `(let ((a 10) (b 20)) (+ a b)) => 32` and not `34`. My first lisp interpreter i managed to redefine `nil` to `t`. The reason was I had implemented `set` and forgot the quote and thus `(set some-var t)` when `some-var` was unbound set `nil` :-)

Comment: [Here is an example](https://tio.run/##ZVHLboMwELznK0ZULXYSKkjS16FVP6ULOCkSL2FTNZf8Ol0vhDTKxfbszs7OrrOysO0wqNI4KNV0xaGoqYw6Q7mjtDRQWdMeL1hrvQBUbvZ9DR@N6r5KTQdlHcMK2Td1nsKkvhaCj0gYI2XKjh1zcnR@L@cuS9w60RrKg0kFDnVRwunRkUgWe6jRTgsvfE5IMlndxARP5aqiNmMnVKU5O7qMMQtY46KKsq6RiShzZhor/L8Hp6@6sipC3rHDXfhDZW8sgsdoFSeb7e7p@eX1LfAGBr9Q0YYzzFXmt5X2X2rfdBU5njY4Wbx/4GRP9wHCtWdATq5fXNdbqIe0yY/waTvqtF1zqLH@lDnZ9DypSDBBGk@CU6EoiyBLhP6RxLG/GAb8DPjmazH/JjHkb0qxic9rXYGQCghVgg222Gk9/AE) Notice how the macro that prints the expression and its result already have the increased number.

Comment: How should `#5r20` be read in your modified evaluation rules? In base 5, "20" is 10, so you could choose to interpret it as "11". But in base 6 (5 being read as 6), "20" is 12, so the final number could be "13". I suppose the base should be left untouched, the same way "#x10" should always mean hexadecimal. Also, negative numbers: do you expect "-10" to be the same as "-9" or "(- 11)"?

Comment: @coredump Just add `#` to the string in my example and it reads `#5r20` as `11`. It uses the standard reader to first read in the whole number so `#5r20` and `#x10` will be read in first and then my reader-macro adds one. Thus `#5r20` is not interpreted as two numbers that should be incremented, but I guess you can mend that with a few lines more. In addition `#.(+ 3 5)` originally became `10`, but with `#` possibly be a number prefix thw whole thing gets read in as one number and the result becomes `9`. I forgot to remove it yesterday and it's an annoying feature when programming :-)

Comment: @Sylwester Thanks, this was more directed towards OP, but I appreciate the details. The task feels somewhat badly specified (e.g. increment both num. and den. in ratios? or the resulting ratio as a whole?) and little bit pointless too.

Comment: It's clear you could do this by intervening in the reader, but it would be pretty fiddly: you need to deal with things like `+`, as well as ratios, floats &c.  There are just lots of edge cases.

Comment: OP states it "lispers often say you can do anything you want in lisp!" and thinks of something crazy. It can be done in Lisp and I'm sure the details (spec) doesn't change the "doability factor". It can be done period.

Comment: Since I made a reader macro it's not  necessarily interpretation. You can compile and run the code quite efficiently since it is as if the code gets filtered and all numbers inflated ahead of compiling.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the replies. Apologies, the spec isn't more clear and comprehensive. As you mentioned, @Sylwester, I was interested in "doability" and some idea of how rather than a fully fledged implementation with all the kinks ironed out. The code you kindly wrote is exactly what I had in mind, something I can play with to explore possibilities. I'll attempt to reword the question to be somewhat clearer. The effect I had in mind is the very simplistic case of "everywhere I type the key 1 the code acts as if I has typed the key 2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a horrible approach to doing what you want.  Rather than dealing with the Lisp reader, which is (for reasons which should be obvious) really not meant to deal with this sort of thing since no-one would ever want to do it in real life, this code intervenes in the I/O system, to define a stream class which supports remapping characters, with the default characters that get remapped being decimal digits.

This is not quite portable CL: it relies on some behaviour which did not make it into the CL standard, known as ['Gray streams'](http://www.nhplace.com/kent/CL/Issues/stream-definition-by-user.html).  Many (perhaps all) implementations actually support this proposal but there is some inevitable variation in how they do so.  There is a compatibility layer, called [`trivial-gray-streams`](https://github.com/trivial-gray-streams/trivial-gray-streams) which deals with all this.

I have not used that compatibility layer here: I just defined a conditionalised package which works in the two implementations I use.  More significantly I have not actually checked if this code defines enough methods on the class it defines for it really to work properly: I suspect rather strongly that it does not.  It does define enough methods for it to work enough for this to work:

```
> (compile-file "silly-remapping-stream" :load t)
#P"/Users/tfb/play/lisp/silly-remapping-stream.dx64fsl"
nil
nil
> (with-input-from-string (s "(print 123)")
    (let ((srs (make-instance 'silly-rewriting-stream :parent s))
      (read srs)))
(print 234)
```

So, as you can see, this causes anything read from such a stream to have this digit-rewriting thing.  On top of this you could, for instance, build a mad REPL like this

```
(defun silly-rewriting-repl (&optional (stream *standard-input*))
  (let ((srs (make-instance 'silly-remapping-stream :parent stream)))
    (flet ((pread ()
             (format t "~&?? ")
             (force-output)
             (read srs nil srs)))
      (loop for f = (pread)
            while (not (eq f srs))
            do (pprint (eval f))))))
```

And then

```
> (silly-rewriting-repl)
?? (defvar *three* 3)

*three*
?? *three*

4
```

and so on.

One reason that this is not really the right approach is that, in the above REPL:

```
?? "a string containing 3"

"a string containing 4"
```

This would not be a problem in a version which dealt with things using the readtable.

Note that I expect any language which supports mechanisms for users intervening in I/O can do something like this, and I expect most reasonable modern languages allow this.  Where CL (and Lisp in general) is unusual is that the language itself is defined in terms of

- a reader, which takes streams and returns Lisp objects (and whose behaviour is reasonably customisable);
- and one or both of

  - an evaluator which takes Lisp objects (not just strings, or files) and treats them as code to be evaluated,
  - a compiler which takes Lisp objects (again, not just strings or files) representing definitions and compiles them;
- a printer which knows how to print Lisp objects (and which is also customizable).

(Note: if there is a compiler then the evaluator can trivially be written in terms of it, so it's possible to have Lisp implementations which have only an evaluator or only a compiler, or both.)

---

Here is the code.

```
;;;; A silly remapping stream
;;;

;;; This uses just enough of Gray streams to define a stream which
;;; remaps digits in an amusing way.
;;;
;;; ALMOST CERTAINLY other methods need to be defined for this stream
;;; class to be legitimate.  THIS CODE IS NOT SUITABLE FOR REAL USE
;;;
;;; This code has been 'tested' (as in: I checked READ did what I
;;; thought it should) in LW 7.1.1 and the development version of CCL.
;;; Other implementations will need changes to the package definition
;;; below, or (much better) to use a compatibility layer such as
;;; trivial-gray-streams
;;; (https://github.com/trivial-gray-streams/trivial-gray-streams),
;;; which is available via Quicklisp.
;;;

(defpackage :org.tfeb.example.silly-remapping-stream
  (:use :cl
   #+LispWorks :stream
   #+CCL :ccl)
  (:export #:silly-remapping-stream))

(in-package :org.tfeb.example.silly-remapping-stream)

(defclass silly-remapping-stream (fundamental-character-input-stream)
  ((parent :initarg :parent
           :reader srm-parent
           :initform (error "no parent"))
   (map :initarg :map
        :reader srm-map
        :initform '((#\1 . #\2)
                    (#\2 . #\3)
                    (#\3 . #\4)
                    (#\4 . #\5)
                    (#\5 . #\6)
                    (#\6 . #\7)
                    (#\7 . #\8)
                    (#\8 . #\9)
                    (#\9 . #\0)))))

(defmethod stream-read-char ((stream silly-remapping-stream))
  (let ((got (stream-read-char (srm-parent stream))))
    (typecase got
      (character
       (let ((mapped (assoc got (srm-map stream))))
         (if mapped (cdr mapped) got)))
      (t got))))

(defmacro define-srm-proxy-method (gf (s &rest other-args))
  ;; just a way of defining methods which forward to the parent stream
  `(defmethod ,gf ((s silly-remapping-stream) ,@other-args)
     (,gf (srm-parent ,s) ,@other-args)))

(define-srm-proxy-method stream-unread-char (s char))
```